# Visual Studio 2012 RC + jQuery UI = Bug?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button, visual-studio-2012

I'm at my wits' end! I'm trying to do something that (I believe) is a VERY simple jQuery UI process, but I can't get it to work. I'm not sure what to pin down as the variable that's causing the issue.

It could be:

1. My code
2. Visual Studio 2012 RC
3. jQuery UI 1.8.22

What I'm trying to do is create a jQuery button and put an icon on it. The icon I want is the `plus-thick` icon.

Here are the `css` and `js` "imports" for the page (is their order incorrect???):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/Default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Content/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the code I'm using to attempt to do this:

```
$('.headerButtonsDiv > a')
.button()
.button("option", "icons", { primary: 'ui-icon-plus-thick' })
.click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text + ' clicked!');
    return false;
});
```

This was my first try (same result as above, by the way):

```
$('.headerButtonsDiv > a')
.button( { icons: { primary: 'ui-icon-plus-thick' } } )
.click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    alert(text + ' clicked!');
    return false;
});
```

There are three buttons that are affected by this code.

Here are the results:

1. The `<a>` elements are correctly converted into jQuery buttons.
2. Each of the buttons correctly has an icon on the left side of the button.
3. Each of the buttons INcorrectly has the `carat-1-n` icon instead of `plus-thick`.

When I go into the page inspector (using IE and/or Chrome), I drill down to the `button` (converted `<a>` element) and see it and its 2 `<span>` sub-elements. While the `<span>` element for the icon **DOES HAVE** the `ui-icon-plus-thick` class applied to it, it **DOES NOT HAVE** any `background-position` applied.

So, although the class **IS** present, it's not actually being applied. When I manually add the `background-position` attribute (`background-position: -32px -128px;`), *"magically"* the correct icon appears ;-).

I think I can figure out a workaround whereby I create the button and then attempt to select the correct `<span>` sub-element and then "manually" apply the `background-position` myself, but isn't that *exactly* what the jQuery library is supposed to do?

In any case, if anyone can see where I've gone off the rails, I'd really appreciate it! This truly is a small issue, but if I can't get **THIS** to work, I'm not confident about the more complicated issues.

Answer (score 1):

I'm glad I saw this answer before anyone else could point out my stupidity!!!

The class I **ACTUALLY** wanted is: `ui-icon-plusthick`.

What I **USED** was: `ui-icon-plus-thick`.

I stared at this for 2 hours and never noticed the difference of a single dash ("-").

Arrrrrrrghhhhhh!!!!!